# Like "rearranging chairs on the Titanic", but for more positive situations

Tags: idiom-requests

I'm looking for a phrase or word that has a meaning similar to rearranging chairs on the Titanic, but means that it's a lot of effort for a small improvement on something that's already working well. Maybe it helps, but it probably doesn't matter. Any good ready-made ones?

Comment: Not quite what you want, but "*gilding the lily*" comes to mind.

Comment: *law of diminishing returns*

Comment: Gilding the lily is very close, which explains why "polishing a..." keeps popping into my head.  Diminishing returns is much more practical.  Thank you.

Comment: "Like rearranging deck chairs on the Enola Gay."

Comment: There's a phrase _like putting lipstick on the Mona Lisa_ but the connotation is more that in trying to improve something near perfect, you've actually lessened it.

Comment: @DanBron: That's perfect. Please post that as an answer.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction I'm not convinced it's quite apt though: *gilding the lily* means either "excessive ornament" (aka overkill) or, less frequently, "making something worse in an attempt to make it better, but not recognizing the value of its intrinsic qualities".  Neither one suggests "may or may not be an improvement" nor "a lot of work put in".  Or do you feel differently?

Comment: @DanBron: I do. Found the original Shakespeare quote [here](http://www.shakespeare-online.com/quotes/shakespeareonflowers.html) / To guard a title that was rich before,/
To gild refined gold, to paint the lily,/
To throw a perfume on the violet, /
To smooth the ice, or add another hue/
Unto the rainbow, or with taper-light/
To seek the beauteous eye of heaven to garnish,/
Is wasteful and ridiculous excess./

Comment: @DanBron: Shakes calls it wasteful, which is obviously true, but he doesn't suggest it makes it worse. So _may or may not be an improvement_ is implied. And 'ridiculous excess' speaks for itself. It IS _a lot of work put in_

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction Well, now *you've* put in a lot more work that I have! If I were to answer now, I'd simply be paraphrasing you and your research.  Why don't you take those last two comments and make an answer out of them? I'll upvote you.

Comment: @DanBron: Nah, you go ahead, it was your idea. I'll upvote. You already gave up the `discretion` answer.

Comment: OK, I was about to ask this SAME QUESTION, so here's my situation: We used to have no website. Karen made us a website, which is a great step forward. Now, a couple years later, people are looking forward to an upgrade, having better graphics, more intuitive links. And I commented, "Wow, it'll be great to have a lighter background, and less type, and cuter fonts..." Wherupon Joyce pointed out that we should be careful about criticizing the old website, which Karen worked so hard on.

Comment: ....So I respond, Karen did a great thing, and yes, the difference between what we have, and NOTHING, cannot be underestimated. BUT, having said that, the upgrade will be an improvement. So we're not "rearranging deck chairs on the Titanic," b/c this is a good thing, not a doomed mission. And we're not "gilding the lily," because we are actually making substantive improvements, no ridiculous excess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> bikeshedding

In software development, *bikeshedding* is an activity that draws focus away from more legitimate concerns to focus on trivial issues that probably don't matter. The word comes from the idea of people building a perfectly functional building, and then arguing over what color they should paint the bikeshed. There are probably bigger things to worry about, and the building, and bikeshed, will be no worse off whatever color the bikeshed is eventually painted.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality